# iOS - iBeacon - Changing UUID using a program

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I am new to iOS and iBeacon.
I am confused about iBeacons's  UUID, minor and major values of the device.

Is it possible to change/reassign the iBeacon device's UUID, minor and major values using any objectiveC.

Thanks in advance.
Alvin

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's possible, but it depends on the iBeacons you are using.
Most manufacturers provide a SDK which allows you to do stuff like that. If you know the commands that need to be send to change the iBeacon data of your beacons you can use Core-Bluetooth and do that yourself. But check if there is a SDK first, because changing UUID etc is the main task of these SDKs.

One example would be the [Estimote SDK](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK).

There is no way to do this with Apples built-in methods only. There is no "change iBeacon data" method. The bluetooth commands that have to be used to reassign iBeacon data depend on how everything is implemented on the actual beacon hardware.

Comment: Would be quite awful if I could go to some place with my iPhone and change the IDs of all their beacons :-)

Comment: If you have the correct SDK (there aren't that many) you can actually do that. Though most production iBeacons use a password or something similar as protection. At least that's what I hope.